# Syncing contacts to iOS device with Exchange

Tags: gmail, iphone, exchange, ios

I set up a Microsoft Exchange account on my iOS device to sync my Gmail contacts. But Microsoft Exchange is ignoring phone numbers that are labeled as 'iPhone' or 'main'.

For example, John Smith:

On Mac and Gmail:

John Smith
main: 123-334-1212
home: 123-330-1002
work: 123-330-8211
iPhone: 123-778-5556

On iOS device (via Exchange sync):

John Smith
home: 123-330-1002
work: 123-330-8211

I'd like to sync my contacts from my Mac to iCloud *and* Gmail, but you can't do both:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a solution to sync iOS and Gmail contacts without using Exchange? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great timing for this question. Google [just announced](https://plus.google.com/+Gmail/posts/fcxdVaH7faC) that they have enabled CardDAV syncing for Google contacts. Visit the [Google support forum page](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2753077) to enable it. Optionally, you can follow the copy-pasted instructions below:

1. Open the **Settings** application on your device.
2. Select **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.
3. Select **Add Account...**
4. Select **Other**
5. Select **Add CardDAV Account**
6. Fill out your account information in the following fields:

   - **Server**: Enter "google.com"
   - **User Name**: Enter your full Google Account or Google Apps email address.
   - **Password**: Your Google Account or Google Apps password. (If you’ve enabled 2 Step verification, you’ll need to generate and enter an application specific password.)
   - **Description**: Enter a description of the account (e.g. Personal Contacts).
7. Select **Next** at the top of your screen.
8. Make sure that the "**Contacts**" option is turned to **ON**.